# How to get confirmed (5 confirmations) bitcoin wallet balance via JSON RPC using PHP?

Tags: bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

I'm writing a script that will send funds that have been wired into a certain bitcoin wallet to another address using PHP and the JSON RPC API.

So far I've got something like this:

```
$x = '0.1'; // <- just redirect coins when the wallet balance is higher 0.1 
$fee = '0.0001'; // <- transaction fee for miners
$y = $x + $fee;

$balance = $bitcoin->getbalance(); // get wallet-balance, here's my problem
$transfer = $balance - $fee; 

if($balance >= $y){

      $bitcoin->sendtoaddress($address, floatval($transfer));

}else{
      // nothing. idle until the script is executed again
}
```

This works great except that

```
$bitcoin->getbalance();
```

Does return the balance including transactions with less than 5 confirmations.

Using the commandline i can get what i want with a simple command:

```
bitcoin-cli getbalance '*' 5
```

Can I somehow send the parameters ('*' 5) via JSON RPC/PHP?

I appreciate any answer because if I cant' figure it out I'll just give sufficient rights to the webserver and use shell_exec(). :-/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm... well.. I figured it out...

According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro

```
$bitcoin->getbalance("", 5);
```

Guess I should read the whole thing next time. -.-